# Почему после анимации scale визуально вью не видно на экране, но клики сохраняются?

Tags: android, анимация, android-animation, animate

Использую `ConstraintLayout` если у меня `ViewGroup` которую я складываю с анимацией `scale` и дополнительно еще делаю `visibility - gone`, но такое впечатление как будто визибилити просто игнорируется и в итоге вью на экране не видно, но если нажать на место где была кнопка на этом вью, то клик работает.

Я вот не пойму то ли это как то зависит от `ConstraintLayout` или я что то делаю не так.

Вот метод

```
private void openUserPhotoContainer()
{
    Animation animXFlipDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.anim_x_flip_down);

    animXFlipDown.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(final Animation animation)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation animation)
        {
            mContentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            animation.setAnimationListener(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animation animation)
        {

        }
    });

    mContentContainer.startAnimation(animXFlipDown);
}
```

P.S.

При чем если я просто ставлю `visibility - gone` без анимации то все работает как нужно. Вью исчезает и ничего что было в нем не кликабельно

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, `mContentContainer` определен с помощью `findViewBiId` (вроде вы не на `kotlin` пишите). Попробуйте yt использовать старую переменную, а еще найти с помощью `findViewBiId`. Похоже на какую-то "рассинхронизацию жизненого цикла" `view`

Comment: я использую `ButterKnife` для баиндинга... да странное поведение. Попробую с `findViewById()`